# Задание правил в RBAC yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте.

В проекте хочу реализовать систему ролей для доступа и редактирования формы.

Существует форма,

роли: [image]

разрешения: [[image: [2]]

правили: [image]

Код правил:

```
namespace app\modules\form\rbac;

use yii\rbac\Rule;

class IsEditingRule extends Rule
 {
   public $name = 'isEditingRule';
   public function execute($user, $item, $params)
    {

    }
 }
```

К примеру.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы User мог только смотрел. 
Для этого мы должны передать переменную false  для того, чтобы не отображалась панель для редактирования.

Вот можно ли это будет сделать с помощью кода правила? И как передать это значение в контроллер, а потом в представление, когда пользователь будет залогинен под user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В контроллере, обрабатывающем запросы на удаление и изменение записей вам нужно запретить эти действия с помощью `AccessControl`.

Примерно так:

```
'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['update', 'delete', 'create'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => [<белый список>]
                ],

                ...
            ],
        ]
```

А ссылки на редактирование и удаление можно завязать на роль пользователя, например, переопределив класс ActionColumn и использовав там роли.

Comment: Ну а все же. 
Можно ли как-то через AccessControl, с определенным пользователем/правилом передавать переменную какую-то? 
Просто, структура проекта не позволяет сделать что-бы ли отдельные экшены 'update', 'delete', 'create'.

Comment: Переменную можно передать как свойство класса accessСontrol или его потомка (или роли). Отдельные экшены необязательны, можно на весь контроллер. Вообще, вы можете в контроллере или во вью использовать Yii::$app->user->can(<rule>, params), где params — произвольный массив

Comment: А можно будет уточнить по поводу задания параметров. Как будет происходить задание параметров. Ну к примеру нужно вставить $item = 2. Как будет правильно записать? Yii::$app->user->can('admin', '$item = 2'). Извини, что прошу разжевать даже такое.

Comment: ['item' => 2], там не строка, а массив. А в твоём коде в execute прилетит этот $params

Comment: А можно будет объяснить как это будет действовать Yii::$app->user->can(<rule>, params). 
Получается, что к роле присваиваются параметры. Они передаются в execute который для правила(rule)?

Comment: Да. В params передаётся текущий контекст. Например для правила editOwnArticle (позволяющего редактировать только свои статьи) можно задавать дополнительный контекст - передавать params[article_id] и в коде правила решать может ли текущий пользователь редактировать эту статью.